# Codeigniter - Working on a "Private message" feature - Sent messages not shown

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am setting up a blog from scratch and everything works great. Now I'm working on a "private message" feature. On my `messages` function in my controller `profile.php`, it shows all the messages that the user received. This seems to be working perfectly fine.

My `view_message` function shows the conversation between the user that is currently logged in and the user that he's talking to. I put the user's (who the logged in user is talking to) user ID in the uri segment.
So, `$user_from = $this->uri->segment(3)`

Here's my code first:
my `profile.php` controller (`view_message` function)

```
public function view_message() {

    $data['page_title'] = 'Read Message';

    $data['messages'] = $this->model_message->message();

    $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
    if ( $data['messages']) {
        $this->load->view('profile/view_message', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('404/main');
    }
}
```

My `model_message.php` Model:

```
public function message(){

        $uid_to = $this->session->userdata('uid');

        $uid_from = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('messages');
        $this->db->where('uid_to', $uid_to);
        $this->db->where('uid_from', $uid_from);
        $this->db->where('receive_delete', 0);
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.uid = messages.uid_from');
        $this->db->order_by("mid", "desc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;

    }
```

My `view_message.php` view (I have removed most of the code and only left the basic code to show what I have basically):

```
    <?php foreach ($messages as $message) :
        $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');
    <div class="timeline-body-head">
                    <div class="timeline-body-head-caption">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="timeline-body-title                 font-red-madison">
                        <?php if ($uid != $message->uid_to) {
                            echo 'You';
                        } else {
                            echo $message->first_name;
                        } ?>

                    </a>
                    <span class="timeline-body-time font-grey-cascade">
                        <?php echo date("g:i A - F j, Y ", strtotime($message->sent_date)) ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body-content">
                <span class="font-red-cascade">
                    <?php echo $message->body  ?>
                </span>
            </div>
```

I'm only able to see the "recieved" messages, not sent. I am not able to figure that out yet. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your database query correct? Is it returning any results at all? Can you try printing them in the model, or  stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: The database query displays only recieved messages. It doesn't show any "Sent" messages. Like I'm able to see the messages that the user sent to the user who is currently logged in, but not the messages that the user who is logged in sent back.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with your join, comment that out and see if you get what you want then you can start working from there to fix the issue.

Comment: @dansasu11 The join didn't seem to be an issue